# Xcode 6 subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to put a view controller inside a scroll view. 
I think I can do it with something like:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[scrollView addSubview:vc];
```

What I don't understand is how to specify my **nib name** correctly, because I have an interface built which I want to use but it is one of multiple views appearing in my main storyboard.

Comment: You can't a view controller to a scroll view. You need to add the view controller's view.

Comment: If you only use `addSubview:` then view controller events like orientation changes may not be passed properly down the hierarchy. I think you need to investigate using `addChildViewController:`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a viewController as a subview. You can add a childViewController and the viewController's view as a subview. But you should probably read up more on how Objective-C and iOS works.